# Need assistance with creating a generator to print out numbers from a isPrime function

Tags: python, methods, generator

There's a working isPrime function that takes in one argument and returns true if the number is prime and false if otherwise. How can I create a generator to print out each prime numbers that go through the isPrime function?

This is what I tried but I'm positive it doesn't work.

```
primeGen = [var for var in isPrime(var) if isPrime(var)]
print(primeGen)
```

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: Will you call this function much time? and is there a range of the prime numbers from A to X?

Comment: May I ask you what this need for generators is about? In your first question here on SO you already asked for one - as I stated, that question is generally unclear, but the generator aspect of it is completely not understandable. Now again you want a generator and give us a list comprehension as mcve... _Why_ do you need a generator or better: what do you think is a generator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach would be

```
def primeGen(start=1):
    while True:
        if isPrime(start):
            yield start
        start += 1
```

Usage

```
pg = primeGen()
for i in range(10):
    print(next(pg))
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I see from `isPrime(var)` that it returns true or false how can you use it in for loop, this doesn't make sense. Do something like this if you need a list for Prime number until n.

```
primeGen = [var for var in range(n) if isPrime(var)]
print(primeGen)
```

Comment: Yea I am new to python aha. Question, what is the variable n? Like where is it initialized?

Comment: n can take any integer value and signifies the range of prime number u want to generate. Like is n is 10 it would return all the prime numbers smaller than 10.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem here is that you need some sort of iterator that starts at 1 and goes to infinity. Thankfully, `itertools` provides one. We can use it to create a generator:

```
import itertools
...
primeGen = (n for n in itertools.count(start=2, step=1) if isPrime(n))
type(primeGen)  # <class 'generator'>
# do not do the following:
for i in primeGen:
    print(i)
    # this continues infinitely
```

which will successively output prime numbers, in sequence.

Note that I use `()` here instead of `[]`. What we want is a generator, not a list comprehension - using the square-brackets will freeze the program, because it tries to build the *entire* list before returning it, and there is no end to infinity. Using `()` returns a generator instead of a list, which is fine.